# How to define Firefox to "allow and remember" Java plugin

Tags: java, firefox, automation, browser-automation

We have a Java application used by about five hundred computers, the recommended Firefox version to use is Firefox 43.

Every time a new user starts using the application or a new PC has to be installed we need to tell the user to manually click the button below and on the following window click "allow and remember".
[Button to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqvQq.jpg)

Searching the web I saw that firefox provides mozilla.cfg file which can be used to change parameters but I couldn't find which ones I should use to "allow and remember" plugin permissions so we don't have to tech every new user to do that (also, old users often forget). It would be great to distribute this file over the network or create a script to run along firefox installation.